# Is the normal distribution where the parameters themselves are normal random variables still normal?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

We denote by $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ the normal distribution where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ is the mean and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ is the scale parameter.

Assume that the parameters $\mu,\sigma$ are themselves normal random variables, i.e., $\mu\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $\sigma\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$. Is the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ still normal? I note that $\sigma\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ might be negative but this should not be a problem since $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ only depends on $|\sigma|$ but not on $\sigma$.

I plotted $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for several values of $\mu_i, \sigma_i$, $i=1,2$. It has a strong resemblance to the normal distribution but it is probably not the normal distribution.

Edit: For clarification I also want to add that when $\sigma=0$ I assume that $\mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$ denotes the Dirac distribution on $\mu$. Hence, at least for $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=0$ the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is indeed normal.

Comment: Likely relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69134/when-is-the-distribution-of-product-of-two-normal-distributed-variables-near-nor

Comment: $\frac {X-\mu} {\sigma}\sim N(0,1)$ so $X=\mu +\sigma Y$ where  $Y \sim N(0,1)$. This is not normal.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh I see, so $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hence, $X$ is normal if and only if $\sigma_2=0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$X=\mu+\sigma Z$ where $\mu\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2),$ $\sigma\sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$, $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and  where $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $Z$ are independent and $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are constant. Therefore
$$E(e^{zX})=E(e^{z\mu})E(E(e^{z\sigma Z}|\sigma)) =e^{\sigma^2z^2/2}E(e^{\sigma^2 z^2/2})=e^{\sigma^2z^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sigma_2^2 z^2}}.$$

Comment: Why did you assume $\mu_1=\mu_2=0$? I don't see why that is necessary. I also don't understand why you compute the moment-generating function. However I agree that the result follows from $X=\mu+\sigma^2 Z$ just like I pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the Laplace transform is a way to answer to your question: is $X$ normal? Now I apologize for overlooking $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2.$ Now, let go, but adding a $Z_2\sim N(0,1)$  such that $\sigma =\mu_2+\sigma_2 Z_2.$

$$E(e^{sX})=e^{s\mu_1+\frac{s^2}{2}\sigma^2_1 }\times 
E(e^{\frac{s^2}{2}(\mu_2^2+2\mu_2 \sigma_2 Z_2+\sigma_2^2 Z_2^2)})\\=e^{s\mu_1+\frac{s^2}{2}(\sigma^2_1+\mu_2^2)  }\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{R}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}(1-s^2\sigma_2 )+\frac{s^2}{2}\mu_2\sigma_2 z}dz\\=e^{s\mu_1+\frac{s^2}{2}(\sigma^2_1+\mu_2^2)  }\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sigma_2^2s^2}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-\sigma_2^2s^2}\times \frac{\mu_2^2\sigma_2^2}{8}s^4\right)
.$$ Beurk, not normal isn't it?